# Stored Procedure or Code

Tags: database, stored-procedures, data-mining, database-performance, data-processing

I am not asking for opinions but more on documentations.

We have a lot of data files (XML, CSV, Plantext, etc...), and need to process them, data mine them.

The lead database person suggested using stored procedure to accomplish the task. Basically we have a staging table where the file get serialized, and saved into a clob, or XML column. Then from there he suggested to further use stored procedure to process the file.

I'm an application developer with db background, more so on application development, and I might be bias, but using this logic in the DB seems like a bad idea and I am unable to find any documentation to prove or disapprove what I refer to as putting a car on a train track to pull a load of freights.

So my questions are:
How well does the DB (Oracle, DB2, MySQL, SqlServer) perform when we talking about regular expression search, search and replace of data in a clob, dom traversal, recursion? In comparison to a programming language such as Java, PHP, or C# on the same issues.

**Edit**

So what I am looking for is documentation on comparison / runtime analysis of a particular programming language compare to a DBMS, in particular for string search and replace, regular expression search and replace. XML Dom traversal. Memory usage on recursive method calls. And in particular how well they scale when encountered with 10 - 100's of GB of data.

Comment: SP:s are good for selection and aggregation. They easily become an unmaintainable mess when other processing (string, parsing, math etc) is involved. Is performance really an issue?

Comment: Maintenance is not one of my concern because if we were to follow the route of using SP, then I am not maintaining the system, the DBA is. But I do not want to stand idle by when I see something stupid is being done, so only argument for me that is valid to him is I can do this better and more efficient since maintenance variable has been taking out of my equation.

Comment: "data mining" is a very overloaded term. It can mean anything from computing averages to complex statistical methods of $O(n^3)$ or worse runtime. Please be more precise. Because some things will obviously be easy to do using stored procedures. Others will be a pain to do this way!

Comment: Nail Identification Error: Hammer meet thumb

Comment: If one of us writes a blog post - would that serve as documentation?! :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are going to throw business logic into the storage layer. For operations like you describe, you should not use the database. You may end up in trying to find workarounds for showstoppers or create quirky solutions because of inflexibility.

Also keep maintainability in mind. How many people will later be able to maintain the solution?

Speaking about speed, choosing the right programming language you will be able to process data in multiple threads. At the end, your feeling with the car n the train is right;)

Comment: I understand all that. But what I need are documentation of what common sense would explain. Without some documentation, my argument is as valid as I believe this but I am not an expert. Like I state I am an app dev, and I definitely do not believe putting any logic into a storage layer. So I am hoping someone in the community may have read something that might justify what I think is true.

Comment: It makes no sense to downvote the answers. The arguments you are looking for are axioms in software development. You will find plenty of documents about that. There is no bad thought about your point, we can just give you more arguing points like maintainability and possibility to parallelisize the algorithm by programming it.

Comment: According to your edit you rally should do it outside the DB layer. You are much more flexible, especially in "XML Dom traversal" and "recursive method calls", which are in no way part of the storage layer. If your DBA is going to do all this, this will just be a proof-of-concept, which will take LONG time and cost incredible money.I can just repeat me and the other answers: The storage layer is not made for this, it will naturally perform much worse.

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted any of the answers, there are users out there are downvote without any comment. Bad but true. As to keeping the DB as a storage layer, I think this is a battle between DBA and programmers, and it will never end, just who got the power. But in order for me to make my case, which I have done a few test cases to prove my point, but without documentation or book written by an export, its hard to prove my point. I work in a very academic/military environment and documentation means more than proof.

Comment: I guess at this point I can assume that not too many people have read book about programming languages vs DBMS performance and have study case for it.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to pull the processing logic out of data layer.Profiling your implementation in Database will be difficult.

You get the freedom and option to choose between libraries and comparing their performance if the implementation is done with any language.
Moreover you can choose frameworks like (Spring-Batch for Java) to process bulk volume of data as batch process.